# How to show when the inequality holds?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous,
> $M=\sup\limits_{z\in[a,b]}|f(z)|$ then
> $$\left\vert\int\limits_a^bf(z)dz\right\vert\leq M(b-a).$$

It's easy to prove the inequality. But I don't know how to show the above inequality becomes equality if and only if $f$ is constant.
I just can deduce that if $\leq$ becomes $=$, $|f(z)|=M\quad\forall z\in [a,b]$. Could someone help me?

Comment: A useful trick is to note that $|\int f| = \int \theta f$ for some $|\theta| = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ were real the result would follow immediately from the fact that equality in the integral implies $|f(z)|=M$ hence by continuity $f(z)=M$ or $f(z)=-M$, so the trick is to force that.

So let $|\int\limits_a^bf(z)dz|=M(b-a)$ hence $\int\limits_a^bf(z)dz=M(b-a)e^{i\alpha}$ and let's consider $g(x)=e^{-i\alpha}f(x), x \in [a,b]$ then $\int\limits_a^bg(x)dx=M(b-a)\ge 0$ and since we are on the segment $[a,b]$ we have that $dx$ is a real measure so $\int\limits_a^b \Re g(x)dx=M(b-a)$ and $\int\limits_a^b\Im g(x)dx=0$. But $|\Re g(x)| \le |g(x)| \le M$ so the comments above imply that $|\Re g(x)|=M$ hence $\Re g$ is constant $M$ or $-M$ and then $\Im g=0$ since $M=|g(x)|=\sqrt {(\Re g)^2+(\Im g)^2}=\sqrt {M^2+(\Im g)^2}$ so $g=\Re g$ is constant and $f=e^{i\alpha}g$ is also constant.